# How to append text to a word in a multiline file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

So someone on twitter mentioned this. You have a text file like so:

```
watermelon
taco
bacon
cheese
```

You want to append the text "kitten" to the end of "taco". Thus, the wanted output is as so:

```
watermelon
tacokitten
bacon
cheese
```

How can you do this in bash?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing bash specific about this;  just use the `sed` program:

```
sed 's/^\(taco\)$/\1kitten/' inputfile
```

Comment: No reason for the parens. `s/^taco$/tacokitten/` or `s/^taco$/&kitten/`

Answer (score 1):

While `sed` is clearly a better choice, academically, here's how to do it in pure bash (or zsh):

```
while read line; do
    if [ "$line" = "taco" ]; then 
        line=${line}kitten
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < test.in
```

Or slightly more idiomatically:

```
while read line; do
    [ "$line" = "taco" ] && line=${line}kitten 
    echo "$line" 
done < test.in
```

Or in `awk`:

```
awk '/^taco$/{$0=$0"kitten"}1' test.in
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly:

```
TARGET_FILE=/path/to/file.txt
LINENO=1 # line number counter
NEEDLE="taco"

for word in $(cat $TARGET_FILE)
do     
    if [ "$word" = $NEEDLE ]
    then
        #echo "Appending $word on line $LINENO..."
        sed -i "${LINENO}s/.*/${word}TEXTAPPENDED/" $TARGET_FILE
        break
    fi   
    LINENO=$(( LINENO +1 )) #increase line number by 1  
done
```

Comment: why? why? first find line number, & then use sed in for loop with line number based address to replace string? clearly, HIGHLY unoptimized.

Comment: Besides, get away from habit of `for word in $(command);do...`; They fail when command output contains spaces/tabs. Use `command | while read word; do ...`; or even better, `while read word ; do ... done < <(command)`